# Does React Native support barometer on IOS

Tags: react-native

Can you access the barometer information from React Native?  I see there is a polyfill for geolocation, but I'm thinking that is not the same as accessing barometer data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The barometer in iOS is part of the `CoreMotion` framework, accessible within the `CMAltimeter` and `CMAltitudeData` classes.

You can import iOS native modules, and the React Native documentation has a [guide for doing so](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html).